# Subset String by Position of Characters in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I can't seem to find an elegant solution to a relatively simple problem in R. I would like to extract characters from a string based on a vector of positions. For example, how could I extract the 1st, 3rd, and 5th characters from `example.string`? `substr` does not work without a beginning and end.

```
example.string <- "ApplesAndCookies"
characters.wanted <- c(1,3,5)
```

Expected output would be:
`Ape`

I can design a loop or function to do this, but there has to be an easier way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution for a single string.

```
example.string <- "ApplesAndCookies"
characters.wanted <- c(1,3,5)

paste(unlist(strsplit(example.string, ''))[characters.wanted], collapse = '')
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1] "Ape"
```

Extension to a vector of strings.

```
example.string <- c("ApplesAndCookies","ApplesAndCookies","ApplesAndCookies")
characters.wanted <- c(1,3,5)

sapply(strsplit(example.string, ''), function(x) {
  paste(x[characters.wanted], collapse = '')
})
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1] "Ape" "Ape" "Ape"
```

Comment: This works well, and I think is the simplest. Thanks! If I wanted to apply this to a vector of strings, I suppose I'd use sapply, right? E.g.: `sapply(vector.of.strings, function(x) paste(unlist(strsplit(x,""))[chars.to.keep], collapse = ""))` Is that the best way?

Comment: I have edited the answer to also include this option. If you use `sapply`, there is no need to additionaly call to `unlist()`.

Answer (score 4):

For a single string and a single vector you can

```
rawToChar(charToRaw(example.string)[characters.wanted])
```

Output

```
[1] "Ape"
```

For a vector of characters, you can

```
sapply(your_vector, function(x, i) rawToChar(charToRaw(x)[i]), characters.wanted)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a function in the package "Biostrings" that allows you to do this.

You first have to [install BiocManger](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html)

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
     install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.14")
```

Next install and load the package "Biostrings"

```
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
library(Biostrings)
```

You can then use the function `letter()` to subset your string. For example:

```
x <- "abcde"
letter(x, 1:2)

"ab"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
example.string <- "ApplesAndCookies"
characters.wanted <- c(1,3,5)

paste(strsplit(example.string, "")[[1]][characters.wanted], collapse="")
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "Ape"
```